# How does SwiftUI know where to find ModelData?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The things is, I just started to learn Apple's SwiftUI tutorial(it's a good one for begginers... I tried learn SwiftUI before but quit for a while, now I'm picking it up)

Anyway, my project tree looks like this (pretty standard cuz I follow the tutorial step by step)

```
   ├── LandmarksApp.swift
   ├── Model
   │   ├── Landmarks.swift
   │   └── ModelData.swift
   ├── Preview Content
   │   └── Preview Assets.xcassets
   │       └── Contents.json
   ├── Resources
   │   └── landmarkData.json
   └── Views
       ├── CircleImage.swift
       ├── ContentView.swift
       ├── LandmarkList.swift
       ├── LandmarkRow.swift
       └── MapView.swift
```

In `ModelData.swift`, apple told me to write this:

```
import Foundation

var landmarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

I searched online and also looked up in apple's document, and I learned the grammar, so I've know how these codes means.

While in `LandmarkRow.swift`, I wrote this

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark: Landmark
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            landmark.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text(landmark.name)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group{
            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmarks[0])
            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmarks[1])
        }
        .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))

    }
}
```

I mean, how did this component managed to find `landmarks` which I defined in `Model/ModelData` ?

I've learnd python, and I know in python we have to do thing like `import [something] from [somewhere]`

Is SwiftUI design under the principle of some specific **Design Pattern** and SwiftUI automatically store these model component(like `ModelData.swift`) in some magical place?
I didn't get... To be honest I know nothing about **Design Pattern**, just heard something about it. Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: `LandmarkRow` is a child view of `LandmarkList` where the model data is retrieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this could be hard to understand if you come from Python... This really has nothing to do with design patterns or anything like that.

On a language level, you can access `landmarks` in LandmarkRow.swift without importing anything because LandmarkRow.swift and ModelData.swift *belong to the same module*, and `landmarks` is declared non-privately at the top level (a global variable).

On a lower, more technical level, this works because you are compiling LandmarkRow.swift and ModelData.swift *together*. Xcode is giving both of these files to the Swift compiler *at the same time*. It's as if you are doing (this is a gross oversimplification of what is actually happening):

```
swiftc Model/Landmarks.swift Model/ModelData.swift Views/LandmarkRow.swift <and so on>
```

So *of course* the compiler can "find" `landmarks` when compiling LandmarkRow.swift. Even though it is in ModelData.swift, the file has also been given to the compiler! It just has to look through the files its been given.

In fact, you can see this happening just by creating two files:

```
// f.swift
func f() {
    print("Hello")
}

// main.swift
f()
```

And compile it with `swiftc f.swift main.swift`, and run the generated executable.

If you want to see the exact command Xcode uses to compile your code (warning: it's very long and verbose), you can go to the rightmost tab on the left pane, select one of the "Build" reports, find a row that says "Compiling XXX.swift", and click on the button on the far right.

[image]

You only use `import` when you want to use `public` declarations from another *module*. `landmarks` isn't public (it's `internal`), so you can't `import` it even if you want to. (There is also `@testable import` which imports `internal` declarations, but let's leave that for now)